# How to change the Form1 to FormMain in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm starting with Delphi and I just find annoying that I get default varuables of Form1. I want to give it other name like FormMain or something like that. So let's see my code:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Code above works fine when I compile.
Now I change next code to:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

And in other file .dpr I also change it to:

```
program mainProject;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  main in 'main.pas' {FormMain};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TFormMain, FormMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

And this gives me errors, what ever I change. I just want to change default form name.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to rename a Form is to use the [Object Inspector](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Object_Inspector) at design-time.  Simply change the Form's `Name` property to the desired value (ie, change `'Form9'` to `'FormMain'`), and then the IDE will rename the Form's class type for you, as well as its associated global variable and DFM resource.

In your case, you did not rename the global `Form9` variable to `FormMain` to match what the DPR is looking for in the call to `Application.CreateForm()`.  And I'm guessing you did not update the DFM resource, either.

Comment: Alternative way is to use the `Refactor - Rename` either from main menu or from code view pop-up menu.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I thought 5hat was for code only? Will that update the DFM, too?

Comment: Holy smoke! I've learned that when you question something, it needs to be taken seriously! And so again. I have a `Unit1` with class `TMainForm = class(TForm)`, the instance was named `MainForm: TMainForm;`. The `.dfm` had as expected a line `object MainForm: TMainForm`. I changed the instance to `MyMainForm: TMainForm` and made a build that was successful. Switched to design view and further to text view of the form and as you say, still `object MainForm: TMainForm`. The `.dpr` shows `Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {MainForm};` and `  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MyMainForm);` (cont....)

Comment: (....cont) I wonder where this would bite back. Need to check later today. Perhaps, you could mention this in your answer?

Comment: @TomBrunberg if the DFM is not updated properly, the Form should fail to load at runtime

Comment: I thought so too, but it doesn't fail at runtime. As I said, I will check this further a bit later.

Comment: @TomBrunberg nevermind. It is because when a TForm is reading its DFM resource, TReader will ignore the top-level class name stored in the DFM. As long as the resource name matches the Form's class name, it still works.

Comment: Interesting about the top-level. Anyway I renamed (via Refactor - Rename) a `TGroupBox`  on the form, from `GroupBox1` to `GroupBoxA` and this was changed also in the `.dfm`. Repeated with a `TMemo` also successfully. It seems after all that the refactoring succeeds  also for the `.dfm`, except for the top level items name, which however has no negative effect (?), or not known currently.